# About ViewModel and View interaction

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I have a question about how this works, currently Im away from college and theres no way I can ask my professor about this question, hopefully you guys can help me out.

So, I've got a login panel made in xaml
(The password thing has a class because of security reasons, http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html if anyones interested)
My question is, whenever I write stuff on my 2 textbox's, I want it to procceed to a next Window/Xaml form. I have tried creating a new instance of a form (Form2 form = new Form2, and then use form.show()) in the VkiewModel but according to MVVM pattern that the professor says, ViewModels shouldn't create Views. How can I solve this?

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SchoolManagement.ViewModels"
xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:SchoolManagement.Extras"
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:LoginViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>


 <Label Content="Email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="338,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Email}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="338,155,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" TextAlignment="Center" />

 <Label Content="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="338,185,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
 <PasswordBox ff:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="true" ff:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="338,215,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>

 <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Content="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="513,243,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" Height="22"/>
```

Comment: I recommend that you research Inversion of Control (IoC) as it relates to WPF, and also WPF window managers.  This is a broad topic with many approaches.  For simple applications it's often faster (read: cheaper) to do away with MVVM purity when it comes to window management.  Don't introduce complexity without a good reason; use your best judgement.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at PRISM or Any good framework which will support MVVM will solve your issue

Comment: MVVM != no codebehind.  If your view does something, like showing another window, that's perfectly fine to place in your UI code.

Comment: I would argue that 'successfully logged in' is an event worthy of publication around your app and not just a view concern. So your shell can then decide which views should be shown and where. Just use your preferred view/region navigation techniques (personally, I use Prism).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to do this without an external framework, you will need to create an event within your viewmodel that the view can subscribe to.

**SomeViewModel.cs**

```
public class GenericViewRequestedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public GenericViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

    public GenericViewRequestedEventArgs(GenericViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
    }
}

public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private RelayCommand _loginCommand;

    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_loginCommand == null)
                _loginCommand = new RelayCommand(x => Login());

            return _loginCommand;
        }
    }

    public EventHandler<GenericViewRequestedEventArgs> GenericViewRequested;

    private void OnGenericViewRequested(GenericViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var handler = GenericViewRequested;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new GenericViewRequestedEventArgs(viewModel));
    }

    private void Login()
    {
        // Do login stuff, authenticate etc.

        // Open new window.
        OnGenericViewRequested(_specificViewModel);
    }
}
```

**SomeWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class SomeWindow : Window
{
    private void OnGenericViewRequested(object sender, GenericViewRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        GenericWindow window = new GenericWindow(e.ViewModel);
        window.Owner = this;
        window.ShowDialog();
    }

    public SomeWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new SomeViewModel();
        viewModel.GenericViewRequested += OnGenericViewRequested;

        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```